# Android ANR on onSensorChanged event

Tags: java, android

I'm getting lot of ANR-s from my players.
Here's how the ANR looks like..

```
 "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
  | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x75646598 self=0xf4d76500
  | sysTid=20631 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf7465d54
  | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=259988 stm=3107 core=4 HZ=100
  | stack=0xff21a000-0xff21c000 stackSize=8MB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
  at cr.logics.runfishrun2.S3DSurfaceView.onSensorChanged (S3DSurfaceView.java:292)
  at android.hardware.SystemSensorManager$SensorEventQueue.dispatchSensorEvent (SystemSensorManager.java:579)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce (Native method)
  at android.os.MessageQueue.next (MessageQueue.java:323)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:143)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7230)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke! (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1230)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1120)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=2 Runnable
  | group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x32c180a0 self=0xf3f84000
  | sysTid=20636 nice=0 cgrp=default sched=0/0 handle=0xf43dc930
  | state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=5 core=1 HZ=100
  | stack=0xf42e0000-0xf42e2000 stackSize=1014KB
  | held mutexes= "mutator lock"(shared held)
```

And this is my code..

```
public void onSensorChanged ( SensorEvent event )
    {
        if ( event.sensor.getType ( ) == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER )
        {
            final float x = event.values[0] ;
            final float y = event.values[1] ;
            final float z = event.values[2] ;

            // Get a free pool item, else allocate a new one
            //
            AccelerometerEventRunnable oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem = null ;

            for ( AccelerometerEventRunnable aer : aAccelerometerEventRunnablePool )
            {
                if ( aer.done ( ) )
                {
                    oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem = aer ;
                    oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem . set ( x, y, z, iDisplayOrient ) ;
                    break ;
                }
            }
            if ( oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem == null )
            {
                oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem = new AccelerometerEventRunnable ( x, y, z, iDisplayOrient ) ;
                aAccelerometerEventRunnablePool.add ( oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem ) ;
                //Log.d ( "S3DSurfaceView", "onAccelerometerEvent: " + aAccelerometerEventRunnablePool.size() ) ;                
            }
            if ( oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem != null )
            {
                queueEvent ( oAccelerometerEventRunnablePoolItem ) ;
            }            
        }
        else if ( event.sensor.getType ( ) == Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION )
        {
            final float azimuth =  event.values[0] ;
            final float pitch   =  event.values[1] ;
            final float roll    = -event.values[2] ;

            queueEvent ( new Runnable ( ) { public void run ( ) { if ( oRenderer != null ) oRenderer.onHeadingEvent ( azimuth ) ; } } ) ;
        }
    }
```

Looks like it happens on this line.. 
for ( AccelerometerEventRunnable aer : aAccelerometerEventRunnablePool )

The thing is that it's not my code, and I have no idea how to fix this. Any workarounds?
Thanks in advance!